# Python SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

The following Python script raises syntax error:

```
def main(number, number2, equation):
    if equation == 1:
        number + number2 = answer
```

`SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator` is the raised error. Please help.

Comment: Sorry that i didnt put the "code look" to the code im a dumass

Comment: What do you expect the code to do?

Comment: The statement is not valid for python. Variables must be left side and expression must be the right side. For more information, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)

Comment: Hey @noobie, Welcome to SO. Congrats on your efforts in learning Python. Keep it up. Statement - `number + number2 = answer`  is not valid. It's because the assignment operator(=) assigns the right-hand side value to the left-hand side. Btw, don't get discouraged by the down votes. Keep up the learning.

Answer (score 3):

You must assign (`=`) operation (`number + number2`) to variable `answer` in this direction.

```
answer = number + number2
```

Variable name is on **right** side and value, expression, object, etc. is on the **left**.

Answer (score 1):

In python you set variables to be equal to the their result instead of the result to be equal to the variable.
So where you have put

```py
number + number2 = answer
```

You need to do

```py
answer = number + number2
```

As what you are doing is making the sum of number and number2 equal to answer which is not possible